# Splitting a string field that contains time information

Tags: arcpy, datetime

I have a text field within a FGBD that contains a date/time and I need only the time as a string.

```
'yyyymmdd HH:mm:ss'
```

And I need:

```
'HH:mm:ss'
```

I've tried .rsplit but I'm not using it correctly. I thought this would split where the space is located (between the date and time):

```
arcpy.Calculatefield_management(fc,"time",!DATE!.rsplit())
```

But this returns the whole string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "time", "!DATE!.split(' ')[1]", "PYTHON")
```

This uses Python to split the string at the space (which returns a list containing the date as a string and the time as a string), and populates the field with the second item in the list, which is the time.

Answer (score 2):

You are close, but the (r)split will create a list. Therefore you need to get the element from the list (-1 for the last one)

```
arcpy.Calculatefield_management(fc,"time",!DATE!.rsplit()[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code instead:
 `arcpy.Calculatefield_management(fc,"time",!DATE![9:len(!DATE!)])`

Len gets the length of the string the square brackets are saying, "Return the 9th character of the string (in date) to the last character of the string"